# Dealing with JPEG Files

Tags: java, image, stream, jpeg

I am quite new with this idea but I tried to open JPEG file in NOTEPAD, & without making any change i RE-Saved it with new name

let new.jpg

but when opened this new.jpg it is firing error in opening, any Viewer is not able to show the image.

Actually I want to open an image in stream of Binary Format(purely Binary) which can be saved in String & on other side it will be rearranged in Stream to save it as JPEG, I want to do this in JAVA. but before programming i tried an experiment as i earlier described but It is raising error.

Comment: It sounds like you want to do something like ASCII85 encoding. Take a look here: http://www.webutils.pl/Ascii85

Comment: its going to be helpful to me thanks BitBank !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Openning a `JPEG` file with Notepad will create error because it will mess up the encoding of some essential `JPEG` Marker.
Try to open your file with an Hexadecimal editing software (I use HexEdit and it work fine).
You should also take a look at the `JPEG` [structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure).

Comment: Thanks brother ! it will help me alot but did you know any way that fulfill my task of getting stream > saved in text file  & whenever i need it will be again re transformed in JPEG encoding > Jpeg image

Comment: You can use Base64 encoding to get a String from your JPEG and later turn it back to a JPEG again.

Answer (score 0):

when you save a binary file with notepad it changes the encoding of some of the characters, that's why it is not recognised as a valid JPEG anymore.
i doubt there's a fast way to "go back" to the original file, it involves finding out which bytes were changed.

as for saving it to a string, what do you mean?

Comment: I want to transform the Whole Stream in Textual way that can be saved in any txt file then whenever i need, any reverse process can be applied on txt file data to get Same Encoded Stream, eventually giving JPEG image.